# No index error raised for range indexing. How to raise it?

Tags: python

I'm using python=3.10. While coding I came across a strange behavior.

```
x = "x"*10
print(x[0:1000])
```

Which prints `"x"*10` with no `IndexError` which is unexpected. Why is this not an error?

Comment: even more strange for you `x[999:1000]`

Comment: This can be useful sometimes: `x[0] == "a"` fails if `x` is empty, but `x[:1] == "a"` always succeeds.

Comment: @kindall Thank god for this comment. Found a use for this right away!